# change value of array of obj from another another arr

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, for-loop

I have two arrays of obj first one is default checkbox permission second is set get module

what am I trying to do is match both arrays of data match then change the value to that object

in defaultArr has users module and getcheckvalue has module name users if both match then check into the next level is defaultArr => users => add and getcheckvalue => module name => user match then change that value in the first arr like   defaultArr => users add => true

I expecting output defaultArr but change that value to true if matches with another arr module

```js
const defaultArr = [
    {
        "users": [
            [
                {
                    "add": false
                },
                {
                    "change-password": false
                },
                {
                    "delete": false
                },
                {
                    "forgot-password": false
                },
                {
                    "getAll": false
                },
                {
                    "logout": false
                },
                {
                    "new-password": false
                },
                {
                    "reset-password": false
                },
                {
                    "sign-in": false
                },
                {
                    "update": false
                },
                {
                    "update-profile": false
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "roles": [
            [
                {
                    "add": false
                },
                {
                    "delete": false
                },
                {
                    "getAll": false
                },
                {
                    "update": false
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "parentDevice": [
            [
                {
                    "add": false
                },
                {
                    "delete": false
                },
                {
                    "getAll": false
                },
                {
                    "update": false
                },
                {
                    "update-disarm": false
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "deviceAlert": [
            [
                {
                    "add": false
                },
                {
                    "delete": false
                },
                {
                    "getAll": false
                },
                {
                    "update": false
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "general": [
            [
                {
                    "alert-types": false
                },
                {
                    "device-types": false
                },
                {
                    "module-actions": false
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "employees": [
            [
                {
                    "add": false
                },
                {
                    "delete": false
                },
                {
                    "getAll": false
                },
                {
                    "update": false
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "alertLogs": [
            [
                {
                    "add": false
                },
                {
                    "delete": false
                },
                {
                    "getAll": false
                },
                {
                    "update": false
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "contentManagement": [
            [
                {
                    "add": false
                },
                {
                    "delete": false
                },
                {
                    "getAll": false
                },
                {
                    "update": false
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
]


const getcheckvalue = [
    {
        "module": "users",
        "action": "add",
    },
    {
        "module": "users",
        "action": "change-password",
    },
    {
        "module": "users",
        "action": "delete",
    },
    {
        "module": "users",
        "action": "forgot-password",
    },
    {
        "module": "roles",
        "action": "update",
    },
    {
        "module": "parentDevice",
        "action": "update",
    },
    {
        "module": "deviceAlert",
        "action": "getAll",
    },
    {
        "module": "general",
        "action": "device-types",
    },
    {
        "module": "employees",
        "action": "delete",
    }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question is a little unclear actually, so my answer might not help actually.

First of all, if you have multiple users in defaultArr.users, do not use array of arrays, use array of objects, it would be much simpler this way:

```
defaultArr = {
  users: [
    {
      add: false,
      checkPassword: false,
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Now you can just map through getcheckvalue and easily check all properties